# How to take an item from any two BlockingCollections with priority to the first collection?

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

I have two [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7) objects, `collection1` and `collection2`. I want to consume items from these collections giving priority to items in `collection1`. That is, if both collections have items, I want to take items from `collection1` first. If none of them have items, I want to wait for an item to be available.

I have the following code:

```
public static T Take<T>(
    BlockingCollection<T> collection1,
    BlockingCollection<T> collection2) where T:class
{
    if (collection1.TryTake(out var item1))
    {
        return item1;
    }

    T item2;

    try
    {
        BlockingCollection<T>.TakeFromAny(
            new[] { collection1, collection2 },
            out item2);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return item2;
}
```

This code is expected to return `null` when `CompleteAdding` is called on both collections and they both are empty.

My main issue with this code is that the documentation for the `TakeFromAny` method specifies that `TakeFromAny` will throw an `ArgumentException` if `CompleteAdding` was called on "the collection":

> ArgumentException
>
> The collections argument is a 0-length array or contains a null element or CompleteAdding() has been called on the collection.

Does it throw if `CompleteAdding` was called on any collection? or both collections?

What if `CompleteAdding` was called and the collection still has some items, does it throw?

I need a reliable way to do this.

In this code I am trying to get from `collection1` first because the documentation of `TakeFromAny` does not give any guarantees about the collection order from which to take the item if the two collections have items.

This also means that if both collections are empty, and then they receive items at the same time later, then I might get an item from `collection2` first, which is fine.

**EDIT:**

The reason I add items to two collections (and not simply a single collection) is that the first collection does not have an upper-bound, and the second collection does.

*More details for those who are interested why I need this:*

I am using this in an open source project called ProceduralDataflow. See here for more details https://github.com/ymassad/ProceduralDataflow

Each processing node in the dataflow system has two collections, one collection will contain items coming for the first time (so I need to slow down the producer if needed), and another collection will contain items coming for the second (or third,..) times (as a result of a loop in the data flow).

The reason why one collection does not have an upper-bound is that I don't want to have deadlocks as a result of loops in the dataflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, short answers to your concrete questions.

> Does it throw if `CompleteAdding` was called on any collection? or both collections?

Both (all) - but only if there are no available elements in any collection.

> What if `CompleteAdding` was called and the collection still has some items, does it throw?

No. If there is available element in the collection, it will be removed from the collection and returned to the caller.

**Conclusion**

Apparently the documentation is unclear. The part

> *or `CompleteAdding()` has been called on the collection*

should have been formulated differently - something like

> *or there is no available element in **any** of the collections and `CompleteAdding()` has been called on **all** the collections*

**Rationale**

Well, I know relying on the implementation is not a good practice, but when the documentation is unclear, the implementation is the only reliable and official source I can think of. So taking the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,6d991bae3e298a27), both `TakeFromAny` and `TryTakeFromAny` call a private method [`TryTakeFromAnyCore`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,8411347eebfd8252). It starts with the following:

```
ValidateCollectionsArray(collections, false);
```

`false` here is a `bool` argument called `isAddOperation` and is used inside the [`ValidateCollectionsArray`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,14400674383bddac) as follows:

```
if (isAddOperation && collections[i].IsAddingCompleted)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(
        SR.GetString(SR.BlockingCollection_CantAddAnyWhenCompleted), "collections");
}
```

which is one of the possible places throwing `ArgumentException` for collections with `CompleteAdding()` being called. And as we can see, this is not the case (question #1).

Then the implementation continues with the following "fast path":

```
//try the fast path first
for (int i = 0; i < collections.Length; i++)
{
    // Check if the collection is not completed, and potentially has at least one element by checking the semaphore count
    if (!collections[i].IsCompleted && collections[i].m_occupiedNodes.CurrentCount > 0 && collections[i].TryTake(out item))
        return i;
}
```

This proves the answer to the question #2.

Finally, if there is no available element in any of the collections, the implementation take the "slow path" by calling another private method [`TryTakeFromAnyCoreSlow`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs,5991b017ca58801e), with the following comment being the essential explanation of the implemented behavior:

```
//Loop until one of these conditions is met:
// 1- The operation is succeeded
// 2- The timeout expired for try* versions
// 3- The external token is cancelled, throw
// 4- The operation is TryTake and all collections are marked as completed, return false
// 5- The operation is Take and all collection are marked as completed, throw
```

The answer to both our questions is in case #1 and case #5 (note the word **all**). Btw, it also shows the only difference between `TakeFromAny` and `TryTakeFromAny` - case #4 vs #5, i.e. `throw` vs `return -1`.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense that it acts this way, but the documentation is unclear. In the `TryTakeFromAnyCoreSlow` method, the 5th condition says "are marked as completed". I assume this means that `CompleteAdding` is called and the collection is non-empty. I followed the code to the `GetHandles` method and I think that this is the case.

Comment: I was hoping that there is some documentation on MSDN to clarify all of this.

Comment: Indeed. Basically the [`IsCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267315(v=vs.110).aspx) property - *Whether this collection has been marked as complete for adding and is empty.*

Comment: I agree about MSDN documentation, but there isn't. If you follow the reference source, you'll notice that even the XML documentation for the aforementioned exception of some of the private methods in question is wrong - it states *Also, if atleast one of the collections has been marked complete for adds.* which is also wrong according to the implementation :(

Comment: Btw, I found a similar question in MSDN forums - [When BlockingCollection<T>.TakeFromAny() return -1?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8848449a-b333-480a-a5bf-ca1b4b971b6f/when-blockingcollectionttakefromany-return-1?forum=parallelextensions) and the conclusion is that it's a documentation issue. [Reported to MSFT](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/498890/documentation-in-blockingcollection-t-takefromany) by [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) and marked as fixed, although I don't see the "fix".